# Lower bound function for a vector array of pair<int, int>

Tags: c++

Suppose the vector array is sorted by the rule :- A[i] > A[j] for all pairs in A[i] (a,b) and all pairs (c,d) in A[j] a>c and b>d. The input array is assumed to be sorted.
Now given an array of the above type ,

```
A[0] = (0,1)
A[1] = (4,3), (2,5)
A[2] = (12,4), (10, 6)
...
```

Now you take a pair as an input, how to find the lower_bound using the inbuilt lower_bound function.
I wrote a code, but it is giving me some [error](http://rn0.ru/show/vfzu95cQpUPOmozxPZTi/). What am I missing ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
typedef pair<int,int> mypair;
vector <mypair> A[100008];
mypair B;
bool operator < (const mypair &a1, const mypair &a2){
    return (a1.first < a2.first && a1.second < a2.second);
}
bool operator < (const vector<mypair> &a1, const mypair &a2){
        for(int i = 0; i< a1.size();i++){
            if (a1[i] < a2) 
                return true;
        }   
        return false;
}
bool operator < (const mypair &a1, const vector<mypair> &a2){
        for(int i = 0; i< a2.size();i++){
            if(a1 < a2[i])
                return true;
        }   
        return false;
}
int main()
{
    int N,x,y;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    int cnt = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
        B = make_pair(x,y);
        // consider A as filled up as stated
        x = lower_bound(A,A+N,B) - A;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: a data structure may also work, but can you suggest any edits so i can get away with an array of vectors ?

Comment: who is to say the user is going to input the values so that the vector is sorted right from the start ?
You need to sort the array before you can use lower_bound because it is an algoritym based on binary search.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck The main problem was with the lower_bound part, so i was testing the problem with a sorted input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function `lower_bound` is also overloaded for 4 arguments:

```
template<class FI, class T, class Comp>
FI lower_bound( FI first, FI last, const T& value, Comp comp );
```

So, you can pass comparator as fourth argument:

```
bool cmp(const vector<mypair> &a1, const mypair &a2){
    for(int i = 0; i< a1.size();i++){
        if (a1[i] < a2)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// ...

x = lower_bound(A,A+N,B, cmp) - A;
```

Comment: Adding anything but template specializations to `std` is undefined behaviour. *The behavior of a C++program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a
namespace within namespace std unless otherwise specified*. Also, this doesn't deal with the fact that `x` is declared as an `int`, but `lower_bound` returns an iterator.

Comment: i have written previous codes(for finding lower_bounds) where just overriding the < operator works, you don't need to put into namespace/pass the comparator as fourth element. what is special when you are dealing with an array of vector<pair> ?

Comment: @AshutoshSingla, It's named `ADL` - *Argument-dependent name lookup*. Function `lower_bound` will look for an `operator<` in the `std` namespace firstly.

Comment: *"where just overriding the < operator works"* - @AshutoshSingla, are you sure, that code works as you expected? Note, `std::pair` has comparison operator already.

Comment: yes, it works normally i don't know what is going wrong here .. have a look http://ideone.com/KRqWTL in case of a data structure (int x,y) sorted about x

Comment: @AshutoshSingla, Your example is OK, but try to replace `data` with `pair` and your code will not compile, since there is no overloaded `operator<` for `std::pair` and `int` in `std` namespace. [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=174804024d2095019d731703f2bde190-86b2e6efcfbc8c9ef8046e90e83130d8).

Comment: yes, Thank you for your help :) and any idea why the exception ?

Comment: @AshutoshSingla, Because of `ADL`. Compiler mets possible `operator<`(template function) in `std` namespace and will not look for another comparison function.